# Heroku DB Push Error / Taps Serve

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I am having an issue with Heroku in regards to adding an integer column to an existing table.

Here is how I setup my migration file:

```
class AddFieldsToNetwork < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :networks, :phone, :integer, :limit => 10
    add_column :networks, :contact, :string
  end

def self.down
  remove_column :networks, :phone
  remove_column :networks, :contact
  end
 end
```

Now this works locally, but when I push to Heroku, I get what most people get:

```
!!! Caught Server Exception  
HTTP CODE: 500  
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  integer out of range
```

If I change `:integer` to `:string`, then adding the columns works and functions great on Heroku. If I leave it under `:integer`, the `:network` model crashes when I create new "network".

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using locally? There's an issue with taps that causes similar errors if you're using 1.9.3 locally but pushing to a server using 1.9.2 (Heroku uses 1.9.2).

Comment: Currently using ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Comment: @RubyNewbie: Regarding the code format: you need a newline before the indented code block. Have a look what I changed, click on `edited ...` above my name.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Much more presentable.

Answer (score 1):

:limit - Requests a maximum column length. This is number of characters for :string and :text columns and number of bytes for :binary and :integer columns.

For phone you definitely use strings, reason is you mean 10 characters. Not bytes for numbers

Comment: Thanks Alisher. Sorry for another newbie question....then in regards to :phone, if I do not want to allow the user to write any Alpha character, just make a rule in the controller?

Comment: You should add validations in the model not controller.  Search for validation gems on rubygems.org before writing custom validations.